# NPE when initializing EntityManager

Tags: jakarta-ee, jpa, netbeans, nullpointerexception, glassfish

I've read hundreds of answers on the same topic but I'm still unable to make it work! I call my EntityManager in this way:

```
@Stateless
public class MyTest {

@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager entityManager;

public Long create(MyUser user) {
    entityManager.persist(user);
    return user.getId();
}  
}
```

Then I call this class by means of REST web services, in this way:

```
@Path("/myapp/{username}")
@ApplicationScoped
public class MyResource implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

MyTest service = new MyTest();

@POST
@Consumes({"application/json"})
@Produces({"text/plain"})
public String create(@Valid MyUser user) {

    MyUser testUser = new MyUser();
    //testUser.setParams(some_parameters)

    return service.create(testUser).toString();

    return "";
}

}
```

When I make a POST request I always get a NullPointerException, since the EntityManager is always null.

Below my persistence.xml, but I guess the problem is not there, since my app deploys well and perfectly creates the tables in the database.

```
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">     <persistence-unit name="myserver-unit" transaction-type="JTA">
<provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
<jta-data-source>jdbc/MyData</jta-data-source>
<properties>
  <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.create-source" value="metadata-then-script"/>
  <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.drop-source" value="metadata-then-script"/>
  <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.create-script-source" value="create-script.sql"/>
  <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.drop-script-source" value="drop-script.sql"/>
  <property name="javax.persistence.sql-load-script-source" value="load-script.sql"/>
  <property name="eclipselink.logging.level" value="FINEST"/>
  <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action" value="drop-and-create"/>
  <property name="eclipselink.jdbc.user" value="APP"/>
  <property name="eclipselink.jdbc.password" value="APP"/>
</properties>
```

Please can you give me a hint? Is there an alternative way to initialize the EntityManager? I'm working with Netbeans 8 and GlassFish 4.

I already had some issues with injection, that's why I call the method in MyTest in the "standard way", instead of injecting it.

Comment: It isn't possible to create your `MyTest` service in this way. You have to to use `@EJB`, what is the problem with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't instanciate a container managed object (like an EJB) that way. You have to inject your EJB by annotating it with @EJB. That is the only way unless you want to use manual JNDI lookup but there's no need to do that.

Also you probably should change @ApplicationScoped to @RequestScoped being a JAX-RS endpoint and all - or change MyTest from @Stateless to @Singleton otherwise you have a context mismatch between @ApplicationScoped and @Stateless

Comment: thanks, it is now working perfectly with the EJB annotation. As a newbie, I was reluctant to use injection features because I already had problems with them (see my previous question), and my first impression is that they complicate life more than they simplify it. However in this case it just works all right!